# Watcher alert if no records matching filter in x minutes

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-watcher

I need to get ElasticSearch watcher to alert if there is no record matching a pattern inserted into the index in a time frame, it needs to be able to do this whilst grouping on another pair of field.
i.e. the records will be of the pattern:
Date Timestamp Level Message Client Site

It needs to check that Message matches "is running" for each Client's site(s) (i.e. Google Maps and Bing Maps have the same site of Maps). I tihnk the best(?) way to do this right now is to run a wacher per client site.

Sofar I have this, assume the task should write is running into the log every 20 minutes :

```
{
  "trigger" : { 
    "schedule" : {
      "interval" : "25m"
    }
  },
  "input" : { 
    "search" : {
      "request" : {
        "search_type" : "count",
        "indices" : "<logstash-{now/d}>",
        "body" : {
          "filtered" : {
            "query" : { 
              "match_phrase" : { "Message" : "Is running" } 
            },
            "filter" : {
              "match" : { "Client" : "Example" } ,
              "match" : { "Site" : "SomeSite" } 
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition" : { 
    "script" : "return ctx.payload.hits.total < 1"
  },

  "actions" : { 
    },
    "email_administrator" : {
      "email" : {
        "to" : "me@host.tld",
        "subject" : "Tasks are not running for {{ctx.payload.client}} on their site {{ctx.payload.site}}",
        "body" : "Too many error in the system, see attached data",
        "attach_data" : true,
        "priority" : "high"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking how to do this in the future, a few things need nesting in query as part of filter and match becomes term. Fun!...

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "25m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "count",
        "indices": "<logstash-{now/d}>",
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "Message": "Its running"
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "Client": "Example"
                  }
                },
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "Site": "SomeSite"
                  }
                },
                "query": {
                  "range": {
                    "event_timestamp": {
                      "gte": "now-25m",
                      "lte": "now"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "lte": 1
      }
    }
  },

  "actions": {
    "email_administrator": {
      "email": {
        "to": "me@host.tld",
        "subject": "Tasks are not running for {{ctx.payload.client}} on their site {{ctx.payload.site}}",
        "body": "Tasks are not running for {{ctx.payload.client}} on their site {{ctx.payload.site}}",
        "attach_data": true,
        "priority": "high"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your condition,It support json format:

```
     "condition" : { 
         "script" : "return ctx.payload.hits.total : 1"
                   }
```

Please refer below link,

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/condition.html
```